# perl read data from textfile

Tags: file, perl, hash

I wanted to get the fruit and info from an input file in order (reading from line 1 and proceeds). The code below is somehow printing the fruit and info in any random order, everytime running the script generate different order, not reading from line 1. Any recommendation?

I am having an input file something like below

```
apple
    text1
    text2
grape
    text3
    text4
jackfruit
    text5
```

and this is the code I am having to call out each fruit and info

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my %hash;

open FILE, "config.txt" or die $!;
my $key;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
     chomp($line);
     if ($line !~ /^\s/) {
        $key = $line;
        #$hash{$key} = [];
     } else {
        $line =~ s/\s//g;
        push (@{ $hash{$key} }, $line);
     }

 }
close FILE;

my %final;
foreach my $fruit (keys %hash){
   foreach my $info (values @{$hash{$fruit}}){

    print "Fruit: $fruit\n";
    print "Info for $fruit = $info\n";


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keys %hash
```

Gives you an array of the keys from the hash, but not sorted. You can sort it with the command `sort`

The whole line would be

```
foreach my $fruit (sort(keys %hash)){
```

Use `perldoc -f sort` to get help of the sort function.

Comment: This only works because the fruit names in the example are already sorted alphabetically, so sorting the hash alphabetically gives the file order. If the fruits in the file are not alphabetical, this method will fail.

Comment: `print join(" ",sort(keys %{{2 => 3, 1 => 3, 0 => 6}}));` gives `0 1 2`. For me i looks right

Comment: I guess it depends on what order you want. Now try it with keys `1`, `11`, `101`, `2`, 22`, and `9`. But, I was talking about the order as they appear in the file, which is what the OP asked about. A hash doesn't do that.

Comment: ok, you mean sort numerically `print join(" ",sort { $a <=> $b}(keys %{{1 => 3, 11 => 3, 101 => 6, 2 => 1, 22 => 1, 9 => 23 }}));` gives `1 2 9 11 22 101`

Comment: Nope. I mean don't sort at all. Preserve order as seen in the file.

Comment: Thank you, I actually misunderstood... omg.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252012/discussion-between-oliver-gaida-and-brian-d-foy).

Comment: @peace my answer is not the right answer to your question, i think. You can mark brian d foy's answer as correct, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things in order that they are in the file, use an array. Each element of that array can be a hash that organizes the data:

```
#!perl

use v5.26;

my @items;
while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;

    if( /\A(\S+)/ ) {
        push @items, { fruit => $1, info => [] }
        }
    elsif( /\A\s+(.+)/ ) {
        push $items[-1]{info}->@*, $1
        }
    }

foreach my $item ( @items ) {
    print "Fruit: $item->{fruit}\n";
    foreach my $info ( $item->{info}->@* ) {
        print "\tInfo: $info\n";
        }
    }

__END__
apple
    text1
    text2
grape
    text3
    text4
jackfruit
    text5
cranberry
    text6
```

The output maintains the order in the file:

```
Fruit: apple
    Info: text1
    Info: text2
Fruit: grape
    Info: text3
    Info: text4
Fruit: jackfruit
    Info: text5
Fruit: cranberry
    Info: text6
```

However, if you want to keep them in order of the file and merely output them, you don't need a data structure:

```
my @items;
while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;

    if( /\A(\S+)/ ) {
        print "Fruit: $1\n";
        }
    elsif( /\A\s+(.+)/ ) {
        print "\tInfo: $1\n";
        }
    }
```

If you wanted slightly different output where each line needed to know the fruit, store that name in a persistent variable in the `while` loop:

```
my @items;
while( <DATA> ) {
    state $fruit;
    chomp;

    if( /\A(\S+)/ ) {
        $fruit = $1;
        print "Fruit: $fruit\n";
        }
    elsif( /\A\s+(.+)/ ) {
        print "\t$fruit: $1\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellend answer, i have never seen the usage of `@*`, could please explain, what it does.

Comment: ->@* is the postfix dereference.